# performSelector throwing invalid argument, why?

Tags: ios, objective-c, performselector, invalidargumentexception

This line of code works perfectly

```
[self explodeBomb:obj];
```

but if I replace it with the following line, I get an NSInvalidArgument Exception, with the reason being an unrecognized selector.

```
 [self performSelector:@selector(explodeBomb) withObject:obj ];
```

The definition of the method is as follows:

```
 -(void)explodeBomb:(SKNode *)bomb
```

I know, this has to be me not understanding something fundamental. But why I am able to call the method directly with no problems, but when I try to use the `performSelector` it blows up?  For the record obj is defined as an ID. I tried changing the signature of explodeBomb to take an ID and then explicitly cast it inside the method, but that threw the same exception.  Anyone know what the heck I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `:` and write like below

```
 [self performSelector:@selector(explodeBomb:) withObject:obj ];
```

Since your method `explodeBomb` has an argument so you have to specify `:`

Comment: Though I would think the fact with object isn't nil would take care of that, but lesson learned, thanks.

Comment: Yes, +1 on comment. And due to this autocomplete, sometimes people tend to forget exact thing. As far as I feel this way. ;)